# How to store user input into MongoDB without specific req.body?

Tags: node.js, forms, mongodb, express

I am trying to allow users of my site to create their own quizzes, but I am having a problem with how to best get their quizzes into MongoDB.

One issue is that the quiz the user submits can have any number of questions, so I don't think it makes sense to specifically reference each question and answer with req.body. Which would mean giving each question and answer a unique name attribute, like below:

```
Question:<input type="text" name="question1">
<br>answer:<input type="text" name="ans1a">
<br>answer:<input type="text" name="ans1b">
<br>answer:<input type="text" name="ans1c">

Question:<input type="text" id="question2">
<br>answer:<input type="text" name="ans2a">
<br>answer:<input type="text" name="ans2b">
<br>answer:<input type="text" name="ans2c">
```

The user can add more questions by clicking a 'new question' button, so the quiz could be very long.

Ultimately I want the user's created quizzes to be stored in MongoDB in a format something like this:

```
[{
  "question": "Which of these involves the analysis of of a business's financial statements, often used in stock valuation?",
  "choices": ["Fundamental analysis", "Technical analysis"],
  "correct": 0
}, {
  "question": "What was the name of the bond purchasing program started by the U.S. Federal Reserve in response to the 2008 financial crisis?",
  "choices": ["Stimulus Package", "Mercantilism", "Quantitative Easing"],
  "correct": 2
}, {
  "question": "Which term describes a debt security issued by a government, company, or other entity?",
  "choices": ["Bond", "Stock", "Mutual fund"],
  "correct": 0
}]
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Not sure how do you pretend to send the data to the server without `POST`ing the body in the request. The data typed by the user must get to the server somehow, why don't you want to use the `req.body`? After that question is clarified, I can help you with the data modeling.

Comment: You wouldn't need to send each answer and question individually in your request. You can create an array of objects that contain the question and it's answers before you post to your server, stringify that array, and pass it as one field in `req.body`

Comment: @DavidEspino to clarify, I was having issues with making a high number of req.body, but now it looks like the best way to go is to compile all the values on the front end, and then use one single req.body to take that data structure to MongoDB. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, @jake1986 doesn't want a separate property on req.body for each question; he wants it in a single data structure.

If that's the case, I would probably write a function for the front end to assemble question objects with properties like the mongo entry you described, and out them all into an array. The array would be sent in a POST request.  You can add these as documents to Mongo by passing this array to the create() function.